# Find dynamically added user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added user control dynamically. My intention is to find which other user controls are related to the clicked user control.

Relationships between the `imagesButtons`(part of user control) in database. Just need to find the user control as whole or the `Code behind` values of the related imagebuttons so that I can find the related `ImageButtons` and do operations on them. Can I do it by using this?

This is the code that am executing

```
Control c = (Page.LoadControl("Product_UserControl.ascx"));
string id = (c.FindControl("imgBtn") as ImageButton).ID;
```

Comment: Well... have you tried? what have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: @gdoron : i have edited my question by adding the code that i am ececuting

Comment: Are you sure this the correct code? string cde = does not do anything.

Comment: @gdoron : sorry about the previous code. I have again edited it. Thanks

Comment: So what's the main problem, you can't get access to that control?

Answer (score 0):

You want to load the Control e.g.

```
ProductUserControl control = (ProductUserControl)Page.LoadControl("Product_UserControl.ascx");
```

Then give it an ID so you can locate it later

```
control.ID = "MyProduct1";
```

Then to find it use:

```
ProductUserControl clickedControl = (ProductUserControl)Page.FindControl("MyProduct1");
```

---

Okay, it seems from your comment that you just want something like

```
string userControlID = this.ID
```

If the ImageClick event handler is inside the UserControl code-behind then this will return the ID of the UserControl itself.

Comment: How do i get the "MyProduct1" in the line

ProductUserControl clickedControl = (ProductUserControl)Page.FindControl("MyProduct1");

as i will be calling the above line in my imageButton click which is a part of my user Control. I tried doing thet, I am getting a null value.

Comment: this doesn work , I dont get any ID of the iamgebutton that is inside the user Control.

Comment: Just cast the object argument of the ImageClickEvent to an ImageButton and retrieve the property 'ID'.